# How to organize and implement Separation of Concern and good OOP with a growing list of queries throughout my app?

Tags: php, orm, repository-pattern, datamapper, dynamic-queries

**Where to put a growing list of queries (mostly all "SELECT" queries) and how to properly access them throughout my app?**
I'm looking to re-factor my app which currently has queries sprinkled all throughout services in my app. I'm starting to encounter DRY issues where I have small and big queries that are similar to other queries I've already written. I also have places where I'm re-writing the same formatting on those queries over and over again. Although I'm not worried about replacing my choice of database, I do worry about later optimizing my queries and wonder if I've made that near impossible by not organizing all my queries better and keeping them in a central place somewhere. I want to follow good OOP and SoC practices.

**An example of where I currently have a query in my app**
For example, I have a service that provides a PDF (or the content rather) of all the staff at a certain event. The service has a method that accepts some input (like "sort", "filter", "pagination limit") and will perform a query with 10 table joins (the query slices fairly well down to a manageable number of rows before most of the JOINs work on it) and format the results in the desired manner for the PDF.

**What I have planned so far**
I'm having trouble trying to think perfectly about my database needs in terms of objects. I do a lot of flexible querying, not all completely ad-hoc, but a wide-range of SELECTs with many JOINs and WHEREs, but I'm trying my best:

1. *Domain Objects*: I will create classes like `usersEntity`, `eventsEntity` (each match tables in my database) and setup properties in them like `id`,`name`,`phone`,etc. that match the database table fields. I may create getters/setters so I can mutate (format things like dates, etc or perform validation). I might create  entities that don't really represent a single table in my database, but perhaps represent a common collection of data that I find I re-use a lot throughout my app. Maybe call it `usersCollection` or `usersEvents`.
2. *Data Mapper*: 
   So I put all the CUD (Create Update Delete...not Read...except maybe a *findById*) operations and stored them in classes called `usersMapper`, `eventsMapper`, and so on. The mappers accept only 1 type of domain object (see #1 above) and will handle the persistence (and maybe a small set of very basic Reads/SELECTs, like `findById($id)` or `findByEvent($eventId)`).

Now this leaves me with a growing list of Reads (SELECT queries) and where to put them?

**The options that I'm aware of, but fall short. Maybe I'm misunderstanding them.**

Let's say I have a query like this

```
SELECT users.first_name, users.last_name, events.name, events.date, venues.name,
venue_types.name, GROUP_CONCAT(user_friends.last_name) as 'friends'
FROM users 
JOIN events ON(events.id = users.event_id AND events.date = :date)
JOIN etc....
```

So what I see in blogs throughout the PHP community is 3 choices:

1. Replace my query calls with something like **Doctrine2** calls. Their DQL doesn't seem to make the call reusable? And things seems to be connected in a way that it would return like 5 entities (based on JOINs) with all properties filled for users, events, venues, venue types, friends. That's a lot of fields I don't need, I just wanted 1 column from each as you can see in my query above. Also, I don't plan on saving any entities after a query like this.
2. Replace all my query calls with **Repository** classes that have methods like: `$someUserRepo->
   findNameAndEventNameAndEventDateAndVenueNameAndVenueTypeNameAndFriends()`. Besides the really crazy method name, I'm not sure what I pass here (conditions like: *sort*, *limit*, a few *where's*?) or what I return (arrays? objects?).
3. Replace all my query calls with **ORM** calls (like Laravel's Eloquent) using their query builders. I don't see how I gained anything by replacing my SQL query with `please->ORM->build->this->for->me->where->andWhere->andWhere->I->dont->know->SQL`. By the way, I'm almost convinced that ORM's are an anti-pattern?

I suspect this is a just a very complicated problem throughout all of the PHP community. **Or what am I missing here?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a [repository](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) is the only sane option you considered.

Here's what you could do.

**Define a repository interface**

This interface will describe how you query certain entities.

```php
interface Events
{
    /**
     * @return Event[]
     */
    public function findUserEvents(User $user, $sort, $limit, array $filters = []);
}
```

or perhaps:

```php
interface Events
{
    /**
     * @return Event[]
     */
    public function findUserEvents(User $user, Query $query);
}

class Query
{
    private $sort;
    private $limit;
    private $filters = [];

    // methods
}
```

**Implement the interface**

Use whatever you like to implement the interface - Doctrine, Eloquent, plain SQL - whatever you feel comfortable with.

```php
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class DoctrineEvents implements Events
{
    private $entityRepository;

    public function __construct(EntityRepository $entityRepository)
    {
        $this->entityRepository = $entityRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @return Event[]
     */
    public function findUserEvents(User $user, $sort, $limit, array $filters = [])
    {
        // query $this->entityRepostory and return a collection of Event objects
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can inject the *EntityManager* instead of the *EntityRepository*.

Only to show you how easy it is to provide alternative implementations, here's an SQL implementation:

```php
class SqlEvents implements Events
{
    private $pdo;

    public function __construct(\PDO $pdo)
    {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }

    /**
     * @return Event[]
     */
    public function findUserEvents(User $user, $sort, $limit, array $filters = [])
    {
        // use $this->pdo to query the database
        // you'll need to convert results into a collection of Event objects 
    }
}
```

Easy. For tests you could provide an in-memory implementation.

**Rely on the interface**

Whenever you need your shiny new repository, always use the interface type hint. This will allow you to replace the implementation whenever you feel the one that you chose on the beginning no longer does the job.

```php
class MyController
{
    private $events;
    private $view;

    public function __construct(Events $events, View $view)
    {
        $this->events = $events;
    }

    public function listAction(Request $request)
    {
        $user = // ...

        $events = $this->events->findUserEvents($user, 'ASC', 10);

        return $this->view->render('list.html', ['events' => $events]);
    }
}
```

In this example, *MyController* can work with any implementation of *Events* interface. It doesn't care if it's Doctrine, eloquent or sql.

**Choose the implementation**

My private preference would be to use Doctrine. It will take care of lots of things like hydrating objects or caching. Shall you ever need to write an SQL query manually for a case when you need a better performance you can always do that for this particular query. Not everything needs to be implemented in a single way, and since you decoupled from the implementation it is easy to change.

Comment: Uh oh! I think this is the answer. This is where my thoughts were going! So the `filters` part would be what? A list of the columns I want? A list of some flags (that I will look for to decide on `wheres`)? I realize I would need to offer flexibility on each query, but not too much, because that would mean I need to split it off into another Repository method.

Comment: I suppose I could have a `query class` that has all the potential properties I could send to a Repo->method, like you shown here (ie. sort, limit, columnsToSelect...). But this class should not be mistaken for being a query builder. It's just a organization of how I will communicate with Repo->methods. Each Repo->method should have some way of implementing constraints on that communication. Like I can't pass any `columnsToSelect` that my Repo->method won't allow (the query ultimately won't allow it). And I shouldn't pass flags that my Repo->method won't respond too.

Comment: I guess just good documentation on each Repo->method will be needed so developers know what can be passed to manipulate that particular Repo->method's query.

Comment: Final thoughts? (before I go ahead accept this answer)

Comment: I only added $filters since you used it in your question. I'd limit the number of parameters and make methods more specific (like findEnrolledUserEvents()). As for which fields to load I wouldn't worry about it, as with doctrine you can select them inside your method and it will still hydrate a proper object (with unused fields lazy loaded - something to be aware of).